# No Default Zoom in Private Browsing on iOS?

Tags: ios, safari, accessibility

How can I set the default zoom level in Safari for private browsing? (iOS 14)

When I go to settings, Safari, Page Zoom and change it to 150% it works in the "non-private" mode but is apparently ignored in private mode.